# How to use CImg in Objective C / XCode?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I know that clang can compile C++ files as `.mm`, but CImg comes as just an individual `.h` file. Regardless if I change the extension to `.mm` or keep it as `.h`, it doesn't work.

First, it complains that it can't find `cstdio.h`. As a result, I changed all the `cstd..` imports to their c counterpart as a

```
// Include standard C++ headers.
// This is the minimal set of required headers to make CImg-based codes compile.
#include <stdio.h> // (was #import <cstdio>)
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception.h>
```

After bringing in the x11 library, I get past the import errors into syntax errors:

```
namespace cimg_library_suffixed {
```

Error: **Unknown type name 'namespace'**

Is this because I changed `cstdio` to `stdio`? I'm confused..

Comment: You're attempting to compile C++ as C. What are you trying to accomplish? Have you looked for Obj-C bindings?

Comment: I'm trying to use CImg, a C++ library, within my iOS project. I haven't found any objective-c bindings.

Comment: Then you could try going Obj-C++. It's a horrible thing to do, but might be the only way to use this particular library. I'm not sure of how to do this with clang, though.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried to do this by changing the filename to `.mm` and it didn't work. Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: You're supposed to compile the file this header is included from as Obj-C++ - the header itself needs no changes.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. I restored the file to its original state, went into build settings and told it to compile sources as obj-c++. Build success! More specifically, I needed CImg for http://www.phash.org/docs/, so I'll be bringing that in next.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in answer form for future reference:

Compile the file the header is `#include`d from as Obj-C++ and the header will get treated as C++ code.